# Qué debo poner en el atributo pattern de un input, para que solo me permita la entrada de números, puntos y guiones medios?

Tags: html, html5, regex, input

Tengo el siguiente input

```
<input type="text" name="ejemplo" pattern="[0-9]{8,12}" title="formato incorrecto">
```

con el que quiero permitir solo la entrada de números, guiones medios `-`, y puntos `.`. Y que el largo mínimo sea 8 y máximo 12.
**Ejemplos:**

- `23-21.23`,
- `2302..134`,
- `-3-7867567`,
- `12345678910`,
- `1-2345678.91`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que conoces el uso de regex, simplemente añade los demás símbolos que quieres permitir dentro de tu patrón

```
<input type="text" name="ejemplo" pattern="[0-9.-]{8,12}" title="formato incorrecto">
```

Es decir: [ **0-9** *(números)* **.** *(o punto)* **-** *(o guión)* ]{8,12}

[Aquí](https://regex101.com/r/GHe7rq/2) puedes ver el patrón en funcionamiento.

*Editado para arreglar el problema con el pipe ( `|` ) tal como comenta @JorgeGómezPrada en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/419091/188830)*

Comment: Gracias! Era lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se define un conjunto o clase de caracteres utilizando los corchetes, las líneas verticales (pipes) son interpretadas literalmente, por lo cual la expresión regular `[0-9|.|-]` aceptaría dígitos, punto, guión Y LÍNEA VERTICAL.

Una expresión regular que acepte dígitos, puntos y guiones, entre 8 y 12 caracteres, sería `[0-9.-]{8,12}`.

El carácter guión (signo menos) es interpretado como metacarácter dentro de los corchetes, para indicar un rango como en `0-9`, a menos que se escriba justamente antes del corchete de cierre. Por tanto, otra manera de escribir esta expresión regular sería `[0-9\-.]{8,12}` donde la barra invertida justo antes del guión se interpreta como carácter de escape para que el guión a continuación se interprete literalmente.

Comment: Efectivamente, no había probado a insertar una barra vertical con ese regex. Excelente aporte, y buena explicación de la necesidad de escapar el guión si no es el último símbolo en los corchetes!

Comment: Claramente, no me dediqué a probar otros caracteres. Muchas gracias por tu aporte, me es de mucha ayuda.